# Writing pixel value to blank matrix

Tags: c++, opencv

having a bit of trouble with this. For a simple example, say I wanted to look up the intensity values of a grey-scale image and write them onto a new array, but say change the intensity by a certain amount. How would I go about doing this with opencv? I've been trying something along the lines of this to try and practice:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){

    Mat img = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED), img_grey, dst;

    if (img.empty())
    {
        return -1;
    }

    cvtColor(img, img_grey, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    dst = Mat::zeros(img_grey.size(), img_grey.type());

    for
        (int x = 1; x < dst.rows - 1; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 1; y < dst.cols - 1; y++)
        {

            dst.at<uchar>(y, x) = x;

        }
    }

    namedWindow("New", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("Original", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    imshow("New", dst);
    imshow("Original", img);



    waitKey(0);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Seems fine when I build it, but I get this error:

First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFD00940D in Test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00000000001BF4C0.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the way that you access the image, you should change

```
dst.at<uchar>(y, x) = x;
```

to

```
dst.at<uchar>(x, y) = x;
```

Check out [**`Mat::at()`**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-at) for more info.

---

Edit: As @Micka pointed out, you really should rename your `x` and `y` since `x` is normally assumed to be the horizontal axis, which corresponds to the "column-direction". Normal use case will be like:

```
for(int y = 0; y < mat.rows; y++)
    for(int x = 0; x < mat.cols; x++)
        mat.at<uchar>(y,x) = ...;
```

Comment: you really should rename your x and y since x is normally assumed to be the horizontal axis, which corresponds to the "column-direction"

Comment: @micka yes, that is where I made my mistake I think.

Comment: @MikeMiller probably in combination with a confusion of the `.at` operator which has row/y coordinate as first parameter (matrix index convention (row before column) instead of pixel access convention(x before y)).

Comment: @micka Yes, I was reading the opencv documentation and remembered reading that the convention was the opposite to my intuition and got mixed up!